# How to install KnpSnappyBundle in Symfony 2.8?

Tags: symfony, pdf, installation

I just need to install a bundle which help me to generate PDF files, but I don't know how to start to install, I don't understand the documentation, the KnpSnappyBundle's documentation says to install with composer to make:

```
{
    "require": {
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.4"
    }
}
```

but I don't know where put such code. Nevertheless I am open to other bundle in which I can create PDF files, and please explain me step by step how to install it, I am a beginner in Symfony.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, "__write/debug-my-code__", "__recommend/search-something-for-me__", "__tutorial__" requests and "__low-effort__", "__unclear__", "__opinion-based__" questions are [Off-Topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Good questions instead, as described in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), have **research effort**, a **clear explanation of the problem** and should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if I had edited this before. Downvoted for time-wasting.

Answer (score 1):

From a command line in your Symfony project folder you can run:

```
composer require knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle "~1.4"
```

And that will install the bundle for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like below after adding it to composer.json under require

 "require": {
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master"
    }

After adding above run "composer update"